# Prevent deep links being opened

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I have been setting up Deep Linking in my React Native app with React navigation, however, I only want to expose one path at present.

How can I implement this so that I only authorise certain links to be used?

So far, my setup looks like this:

```
export default function App() {
  
  const config = {
    screens: {
      SignIn: {
        path: 'SignIn/:verificationStatus',
        parse: {
          verificationStatus: verificationStatus => `${verificationStatus}`,
        },
      },
    },
  };

  const linking = {
    prefixes: ['myapp://'],
    config,
  };
}
```

So as an example, if I navigate to `myapp://SignUp` via safari, it will take me to that screen, but I don't want users to be able to do this.

The documentation states I can add `NotFound: '*',` to my config to handle links that are not valid, but this doesn't appear to stop being able to navigate to genuine paths within my app.